# How can I get pywinrm to connect to a remote Windows machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was making a hello world for understanding how to use pywinrm module and I've come across an error I can't solve.

I've tried using both versions 0.1.1 and 0.0.3 and I'm using Python 3.4.3 on a Windows 7 box.

This is the program:

```
import pywinrm

s = winrm.Session('windows-myhostname', auth=('myusername', 'mypassword'))

r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])

print (r.status_code)
print (r.std_out)
```

Which I copied from example usage on github and got this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "My_program_path_here.py", line 18, in <module>
      r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\winrm\__init__.py", line 29, in run_cmd
      shell_id = self.protocol.open_shell()
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\winrm\protocol.py", line 121, in open_shell
      rs = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(rq))
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\winrm\protocol.py", line 193, in send_message
      return self.transport.send_message(message)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\winrm\transport.py", line 108, in send_message
      response = self.opener.open(request, timeout=self.timeout)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 461, in open
      req = meth(req)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1112, in do_request_
      raise TypeError(msg)
    TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

source: https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I downloaded the version listed in another issue and that worked: https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/95